# Using function enum to render components in React-native app

Tags: react-native

I am following [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react/#enums) link to render components using enum instead of several if-else conditions. My code looks like-

```
render(){
    const _renderHelper = (scene, index) => ({
        'ComponentType1': <Text>Test</Text>,
        'ComponentType2': <Text>Test</Text>,
    });

    return (
        <View>
            {
                this.props.scene.components.map((scene, sceneIndex) => {
                    _renderHelper(scene, sceneIndex)[scene.componentType]
                })
            }
        </View>
    )
```

But nothing renders in the app.